# How to Stop Keyframe Animation

Tags: css, css-animations

Can you please let me know how I can stop a keyframe animation? In following example the div element is looping in backing to top and moving to down again. Hoe can I stop function after the div riches `to{}` condition?

```
<style> 
div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    animation:mymove 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes mymove
{
    from {top:0px;}
    to {top:200px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from {top:0px;}
    to {top:200px;}
}
</style>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) property with `forwards` as value.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode):

> **`forwards`**
>    The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe
>   encountered depends on the value of `animation-direction` and
>   `animation-iteration-count`.

Here you go:

```css
div {
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s forwards; /* Safari and Chrome */
    /* Add other vendor-prefixes if needed */
    animation: mymove 5s forwards;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/VXCXL/6/)**.

Comment: Hi Hashem, thanks for reply but this is not working for me! Can you please take a look at this example :http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/VXCXL/4/ to see it is not working

Comment: As you can see from the example the box transparency back to .5 at the end of the css rule again.

Comment: @Behseini Sorry, the electricity went off while I was adding more details. You should use the `forwards` keyword in `animation` property as you're using the shorthand syntax.

Answer (score 0):

That "infinite" in your animation-count is the problem. It actually means "infinite". Remove it, and add fill-mode:forwards, and you'll be done.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for reply, Can you please take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/VXCXL/4/ to see it is not working for me?

Comment: This fiddle is working for me in firefox, chrome and safari. (although you should also have a -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards for completeness). Are you using IE 9 or below? If so, animations are not supported there.

Answer (score 0):

simple.

you need to play with javascript. with css directly! is not possible.

I put a example on jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/s4rmw/

The code:

```
<div class="animation"><h2>¡HOVER ME!</h2></div>
```

this div have a animation . when hover ! the animation is stopped

is what I mean by your question!

regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply using `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` in CSS within your div.

Here's your updated code for example:

```
<style> 
div
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    animation:mymove 5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes mymove
{
    from {top:0px;}
    to {top:200px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /* Safari and Chrome */
{
    from {top:0px;}
    to {top:200px;}
}
</style>
```

As you can see, at the bottom of div I have added `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

This method is much simpler than using JS and has less moving parts.